# How do I delete multiple records using REST API

Tags: arrays, spring-boot, jpa, collections, rest

Am new to Springboot, I have develop the resource to delete the record by ID, now I like delete selected multiple records.
Example: I like to delete 3 records out of 10 records in single request

Controller class:

```
 @ApiHeader(
            apiOperation = "delete a Content Manage by id",
            apiOperationNotes = "delete a Content Manage by id"
    )
    @PostMapping(value = UriConstants.CONTENT_MANAGE_DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void deleteContentManage(@PathVariable("content_manage_id") int contentmanageId) {
        contentManageService.deleteContentManage(contentmanageId);
    }
```

Service Class:

```
  @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void deleteContentManage(int contentmanageId) {
        Optional<UserContentManage> optional = userContentManageRepository.findById(contentmanageId);
        if(!optional.isPresent()){
            log.error("Exception occurs while not found content manage ({}) in deletion. ", contentmanageId);
            throw new GenericBadException(StaffNotificationExceptionEnum.CONTENT_MANAGE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION);
        }
        userContentManageRepository.deleteById(contentmanageId);
    }
```

JPA Class:

```
public interface UserContentManageRepository extends JpaRepository<UserContentManage, Integer> {
}
```

please suggest me how do I delete selected multiple records.

Comment: get the list of id's in the POST request and fetch all entities based on the id's.
and do soft delete or hard delete based on your requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add method in Repository like

```java
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("delete from UserContentManagep where u.id in(:integers)")
void deleteByIdIn(List<Integer> integers);
```

If you have implemented soft delete in project you can do soft delete like below:

```java
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("update  UserContentManagep u set u.active = false where u.id in(:integers)")
void softDeleteAllIds(List<Integer> integers);
```

And from service class you can try to call as

```java
public void deleteAllBYIds(List<Integer> integers) {
    personRepository.deleteByIdIn(integers);
}
```

Fully working example:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Person> list() {
        return personService.list();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Person create(@RequestBody Person car) {
        return personService.save(car);
    }


    @DeleteMapping
    public String delete(@RequestParam("ids") List<Integer> ids) {
        System.out.println("deleting");
        personService.deleteAllBYIds(ids);
        return String.join(",", ids.stream().map(value ->  Integer.toString(value)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }


}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Where(clause = "active = true") // selecting only items which are active
class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private boolean active = true;
}

@Service
class PersonService {
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    PersonService(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Person save(Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Iterable<Person> list() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public PersonDTO findPersonByName(String name) {
        return personRepository.findPersonsByName(name);
    }

    public void deleteAllBYIds(List<Integer> integers) {
//        personRepository.deleteByIdIn(new ArrayList<>(integers));
        personRepository.softDeleteAllIds(integers);

        System.out.println("deleted adnlakdjakldlas");
    }
}

interface PersonDTO {
    String getName();

    Collection<String> getPersonEvents();
}

@Repository
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {
    PersonDTO findPersonsByName(String name);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("delete from Person p where p.id in(:integers)")
    void deleteByIdIn(List<Integer> integers);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("update  Person p set p.active = false where p.id in(:integers)")
    void softDeleteAllIds(List<Integer> integers);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a jpa query method that brings all records belong to id.

```
public interface UserContentManageRepository extends JpaRepository<UserContentManage, Integer> {
       List<UserContentManage> findAllById(Integer id);  
}
```

After that you can do deleteAll() operation on List.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void deleteContentManage(int contentmanageId) {

    List<UserContentManage> userContentManageList = userContentManageRepository.findAllById(contentmanageId);
    if(userContentManageList == null){
        log.error("Exception occurs while not found content manage ({}) in deletion. ");
        throw new GenericBadException(StaffNotificationExceptionEnum.CONTENT_MANAGE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION);
    }

    userContentManageRepository.deleteAll(userContentManageList );
}
```